# Did Gus greenlight the killing of the young boy?

Tags: breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad, right after Walt and Jessie agree to work together for Gus, and later find out that the 2 men who killed Combo were using a little boy.

That lead to a confrontation, and we learn that Gus ordered his men and Jessie to shake hands and ordered his men not to use kids anymore.

We then learn about the death of the little boy.

Did Gus order his men to kill the boy (off screen)?
If yes, what will he accomplish?
If not, what will the men accomplish?

In anyway, I see no logical reasoning for anyone to kill the boy.
But judging by the no-reaction from Gus to the boy's death, I would say: he is OK with it.

Comment: The two men likely killed the boy to spite Jesse because they knew he didn't like them for using kids. They didn't know that Combo was his friend, but Jesse let them know his concern about kids when Jesse told Gus about the kids.